# Magento Block construct - use _construct or __construct?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am a little bit confused. I read Alan Storm's excellent article about [Magento Block Lifecycle Methods](http://alanstorm.com/magento_listener_lifecycle_block) and as far as I understand one should be using the `protected _construct()` method to initialize the block. In my case I just want to set the right block template. So I assume I should be using

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('stenik/qaforum/forum.phtml');
}
```

However, when I look at the blocks of some of the core Magento modules, they seem to use the php __construct method to do it. For example `Mage_Poll_Block_Poll`, `Mage_ProductAlert_Block_Price`, `Mage_Rating_Block_Entity_Detailed`, `Mage_Review_Block_Form`

Although both ways actually work, I'd like to know what is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's ultimately academic, but the Right Way To Do It® is to override the Magento constructor i.e. `_construct` as requested by the core team in [`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L169):

```
/**
 * Internal constructor, that is called from real constructor
 *
 * Please override this one instead of overriding real __construct constructor
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    /**
     * Please override this one instead of overriding real __construct constructor
     */
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right advice, but this isn't 100% academic — when you override the `__construct` method you introduce the possibility of not calling the parent `__construct`, or calling the parent `__construct` and removing constructor arguments.  This can create inconsistencies in how blocks behave when used in layout xml updates.

Comment: Worth pointing out, as I my answer assumes that developers always Do The Right Thing®.

Comment: This is a neat solution, I wish Magento applied this globally. Only some classes call this `_construct` during the real construct so it's not universally possible to use this in overrides. I'm still forced to inject 20 objects and call `parent::__construct` with those 20 parameters in many cases